# Meaning of square brackets when there is no comma to determine row or column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have this code which produces new columns in my R data frame:

```
for (i in 2:7){
  v <- apply(x[,c(i,i+14,i+28, i+42)],1,sum,na.rm=T)
  x[paste("income", i-1)] <- v
}
```

Why is there no need for a comma before the beginning of the paste function? My understanding is that in order to index a column when indexing with square brackets, then it should appear after a comma,like so:

```
 x[,paste("income", i-1)]
```

Comment: It is list subsetting, since data frames are lists of columns.

Comment: Could you provide some example data? My initial thought is that your apply creates a vector, so you do not have extra columns and can use x[paste("income", i-1)].

Comment: See `?"["` for a detailed discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All data.frames are also lists, with each column being an element of the list. In `?[.data.frame`, it says

> When `[` and `[[` are used with a single vector index (`x[i]` or `x[[i]]`), they index the data frame as if it were a list.

So, `x[1]` follows list indexing: it returns just the first element (column) as a data.frame. You could also specify multiple columns this way: `x[1:3]` returns a data.frame of the first three columns from `x`.

Answer (score 4):

In R there are two types of subsetting. For further Information read [Subsetting: Simplifying vs preserving](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) in Advanced R by Hadley Wickham. Alternatively you can type `?"["`. The simplifying subsetting simplifies the datatype while the preserving subsetting keeps the datatype.

- If you do simplyfing subsetting with a dataframe you might get a onedimensional datastructure, e.g. a vector. `x[, 1]` or `x[[1]]` or `dplyr::select(x,1)`
- If you do preserving subsetting with a dataframe the dataframe stays a dataframe.`x[, 1, drop = F]` or `x[1]`

---

Let us make a quick example:

```
mtcars[2] %>% head(5)
```

gives you

```
                    cyl
Mazda RX4             6
Mazda RX4 Wag         6
Datsun 710            4
Hornet 4 Drive        6
Hornet Sportabout     8
```

While

```
mtcars[,2] %>% head(5)
```

gives you

```
6 6 4 6 8
```

---

```
 mtcars[2] %>% typeof()
```

gives you

```
"list"
```

While

```
mtcars[,2] %>% typeof()
```

gives you

```
"double"


mtcars[2] %>% class()
```

gives you

```
"data.frame"
```

while

```
mtcars[,2] %>% class()
```

gives you

```
 "numeric"
```